# How do I not include part of a string in the captured group of regex

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

```
    String  "Ap: SV, Classe Store Stat: AC,"
```

I use negative lookaround so i can grab AC after the string Stat:

```
(?!Stat:)(\s\D\D),
```

But it Captures

1. SV,
2. AC,

I only want to capture Just AC,.  How do i do this.  I"m fairly a novice when it comes to regex.

~W

Comment: Try [`(?<=Stat:\s)\D\D,`](https://regex101.com/r/SHB3tj/1). What is your regex flavor? BTW, `\D` matches any char that is not digit, maybe `[a-zA-Z]{2}` instead of `\D\D` will do better.

Comment: It worked.  I'm currently using csharp.  what does the ?<= mean.  I was using http://www.regextester.com/ to test my regex but i remember seeing ?<= but it didn't work for that site but when i tested it out in my code it worked.

Comment: I forgot thanks wiktor stribizew

Comment: `?<=` is a lookbehind. You were using a begative lookahead instead of lookbehind.

Comment: Use http://regexhero.net or http://regexstorm.net to test .NET regexps online. There are others, but these ones are easy to use and the former provides a nice way of benchmarking regexps.

Answer (score 1):

In .NET regex, you may use infinite lookbehind, or capturing to get what you need:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"\bStat:\s*(\D\D,)");
if (m.Success) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CbStat%3A%5Cs*%28%5CD%5CD%2C%29&i=Ap%3A%20SV%2C%20Classe%20Store%20Stat%3A%20AC%2C).

To get the value into `m.Value` straight, a lookbehind could be used like this:

```
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"(?<=\bStat:\s*)\D\D,");
if (m.Success) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5CbStat%3A%5Cs*%29%5CD%5CD%2C&i=Ap%3A%20SV%2C%20Classe%20Store%20Stat%3A%20AC%2C).

Capturing looks more efficient and versatile in general.

Note: `\b` is a word boundary, if you do not care to match `Stats` as a whole word, remove it.